# Convention badge does not show on the new Badges sections

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

[image: Convention badge does not show on the new Badges sections]
I have to say that the new badges section looks great. But then I notice that there where some badges that where not showing up there like **Convention**

is this a bug or is there a reason why **Convention, Talkative** and others are not there?

I looked in all the categories for them but I could not find them

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it's because you have those badges.

Comment: Please report bugs with the new profile layout on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: I don't have those badges, I also looked in the ALL, Silver, and Bonce, respectively

Comment: My bad, [you do have talkative](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/884/talkative?userid=1380867) but not convention.

Comment: its OK. Actually I am trying to get convention. that is how I notice it was not there